# I need to use a picture in a webview to zoom it

Tags: android, resources, webview

I succeded to set apicture in the sdcard of the emulator to simulate the work of the picture in a webview but I don't know how to set it in the final apk package.

The picture is called map.png and is set either in drawable and assets but I unsuccessfully tried many way to load it in the ...loadUrl(...)

This is my code I wish someone can help me.

```
public class Map extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webMap);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("file://mnt/sdcard/map.png");
```

This is the new edited code that works in the emulator from asset, where do I have to put your new code to make anything working from the package.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/map.png");
        setContentView(myWebView);
```

Please, use my picture filename otherwise I don't understand it.

Comment: can you be more specific? what happens when you run the app? you just see a blank screen or something?

Comment: I didn't export it but the guy who helped me to set into the sdcard emulator said that it was not enough to push the picture in the emulator via DDMS to get it into the final package. Anyhow, I worked around the previously problem and I succeeded to get file from assets this is the final code I added and it works in the emulator so I think it would be in the final package if it is in the assets

Comment: myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_drawable/map");
  setContentView(myWebView);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again. I am...

I have a basic way for this.. just put your files in Assets directory and at runtime copy that files in either Internal storage or External Storage(sdcard).

like,

```
    try {
     // Open your local file as the input stream
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("image.png");

     // Path to the just created empty file
   String outFileName = "/data/data/<Package Name>/files/newImage.png";

     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

     // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
              {
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {

    Log.e("error", e.toString());

    }
```

Comment: thanx I try to understand it and I will make the attempt.

Comment: when you want to get something or within from your app package then use either asset dir or raw dir, internal storage these files are contains with your application package. if you put any file in sdcard then its only for when you use that sdcard for your app. so the file conttains with sdcard are not inclued in your appliction's package. Thanks.

Comment: ok, sorry my dumbness can you say me where I have to put the map.png I have in the asset and if I can change MyContext with this.getAsset cause I don't understand it well. Do I have to supply a name also for myInput? thanx

Comment: you can put your file map.png file in asset directory then using above code just copy that file in internal storage files directory.

Comment: thank you. I find it difficult to understand. I'm using the previous solution we developed together that it's easier... myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/map.png");

Comment: don't worry. its not difficult, in this way one file is put in your asset directory by you for including in package. and I mentioned the above method is just copy that file into internal storage means at location "/data/data/<package name>/files" directory. so then you can easily refer with file tag. Thanks.

Comment: ok. I understand a little bit. I set the file in the asset then I retrieved with file:/// and it works fine for my little need. Besides, I set the map.png in the asset and created a html referencing the picture then I recall the html file in the WebView to get it centered and correct scaled at start. Thanks for the precious help